# Confusión con la conjugación "abrid"

Tags: diferencias-regionales, conjugación, conjunciones

Mi maestra en mi primera semana de mi segundo año de español nos enseñó que *abrid* es equivalente a *abran*, y que la diferencia es regional (yo no recuerdo los regiones).

Sin embargo, en mi primer año de español solamente aprendí *abran* en presente (aprendí presente, pretérito, presente progresivo, imperativo y algunas conjugaciones irregulares).

Mis preguntas:

- ¿Por qué es *abrid* correcto?
- ¿Qué regiones usan *abrid* y cuáles *abran*?
- ¿Cuál es la razón de la diferencia?

Nota: prefiero un repuesta en inglés porque completé solamente un año de español.

Comment: This question and the previous one that you posted are related to each other. The root of your confusion resides in the use of the "vosotros" form and its variations. The following post explains pretty accurately the above mentioned topic: http://www.livinglanguage.com/blog/2014/10/21/when-to-use-vosotros/

Comment: @JoseMaria Gracias por la recurso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*¡Abran!* is acceptable in all parts of the Spanish speaking world where it means *open!* as a command directed to *y'all* (as opposed to *you*).

*Abrid* likewise means *open!* and is directed to *y'all*, but in the regions that use it, it is used as an informal *y'all* (with *abran* in turn being formal).  It is used in Spain and Equitorial Guinea; American Spanish does not use it.  In American Spanish, *abran* is neither formal nor informal, it's just the universal plural command.  Here are the commands for different subjects:

```
 subject  command  subject  formality     region
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      tú  abre     you      informal      all
     vos  abrí     you      informal      AR/UY/PY (and other regions)
   usted  abra     you      formal        all
nosotros  abramos  we       unspecified   all
vosotros  abrid    y'all    informal      ES/GQ
 ustedes  abran    y'all    formal        ES/GQ
 ustedes  abran    y'all    unspecified   all but ES/GQ
```